# for loop in R which skips some iterations

Tags: r, math

my for loop should execute every 50th time in time period of 1000, in matlab there is something like this 1:50:1000 do we have anything simimlar in R? please let me know
starting at one with increments of 50 until 1000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - Possibly the cleanest solution using `apply` (no loop):**

`apply(stored[seq(1,1000,50), ], 1, yourfunction)`   # where 1 indicates over rows.

**Using modulo (loop)**

My usual way of doing things is using modulo to get the required behavior. For example, print the iteration every 50 iterations while doing some action on every iteration:

```
stored <- 1:1000
for (i in 1:1000) {
 stored[i] <- rnorm(1)
 if (i %% 50 == 0) { print(i) }
}
```

This will allow full control, as you can also do other stuff every, say 100 iterations by adding another `if i modulo x == 0, then ...`

The problem with the sequence method is that you cannot store efficiently in a loop:

```
stored <- 1:1000
for (i in seq(0,1000,by=50)) {
 stored[i] <- rnorm(1)
 print(i)
}
```

The printing will be fine, but the resulting vector will be:

```
  [1]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
   [7]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [13]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [19]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [25]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [31]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [37]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [43]          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
  [49]          NA -0.73339457  ....  ...    ... etc
```

To solve this, you also have to do some dividing, so I found it to be most efficient to just use a normal loop and then use modulo to have perfect control.

**Using `sapply` (no loop)**

As you pointed out in your comment, you want to actually store something, and for that a loop over a sequence will leave you with holes. So you can use `sapply` (for apply family documentation, read [this](http://nsaunders.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/a-brief-introduction-to-apply-in-r/))

Normally, one could use `sapply(1:1000, function(x) mean(stored[x,]))`, where the function could be anything. If you want for every iteration, there are shortcuts like colMeans.

However, since you want a sequence, you can use `sapply`, and feed it a variable argument.

```
seqMean <- function(x) {
   mean(stored[x,])
}

sapply(seq(1,1000,50), function(x) seqMean(x))
```

or in short:

```
sapply(seq(1,1000,50), seqMean)
```

Comment: +1 to offset downvote in the absence of an explanation for downvoting what appears to be a helpful and thorough answer.

Comment: Downvoted because looping and doing a modulo check is a truly awful way of doing it. Slow, ugly and needless. As for your listed problem it's trivially easy to solve simply by appending to the list rather than writing to the `i`th position. Your edit at least includes a decent method of doing it first.

Comment: I'm confident that appending will be much slower in the long run than doing a modulo every time, as modulo will be linear time and appending won't be.

Comment: @JackAidley Good to hear your reasoning. It would be constructive if you would put your solution in code (perhaps using `microbenchmark`) for the benefit of the original questioner and of course the wider community.

Comment: @Dualinity am running into errors with this stored , sorry if its a simple error to figure out but am not able to seqMean <- function(x) {
   mean(stored[x,])
}

Error in mean(stored[x, ]) : object 'stored' not found

Comment: replace 'stored' with the actual matrix you are using.

Comment: @JackAidley Appending is a quadratic function of n, so good luck with that.

Comment: @dualinity looks like the vector is way too big Error: cannot allocate vector of size 352.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
Before saying anything else I would like to thank you for all the time you spent trying to help me. Clean slate approach. My vector has prices of 10000 stocks over 1000 time periods. For every fifty periods I need to average the prices of these 10000 stocks and pick the top 1000 out 10000. What is the best approach?

Comment: @Dualinity: Appending's no slower than what you're doing if you do it properly. You know the array size beforehand so you can preallocate. But that's not the issue, the issue is your dire loop and then check modulo approach, it's strictly inferior to `for (i in seq(0, 1000, by=50)` in every possible way. It's just terrible advice.

Comment: Appending means no preallocation.

Answer (score 3):

There's a `by` argument to the `seq` function :

```
R> seq(0,1000,by=50)
 [1]    0   50  100  150  200  250  300  350  400  450  500  550  600  650
[15]  700  750  800  850  900  950 1000
```

So you can use :

```
R> for (i in seq(0,1000,by=50)) print(i)
[1] 0
[1] 50                                                                                                                                                               
[1] 100                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 150                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 200                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 250                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 300                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 350                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 400                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 450                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 500                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 550                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 600                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 650                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 700                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 750                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 800                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 850                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 900                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 950                                                                                                                                                              
[1] 1000
```

Comment: awesome , thank you. Now if I can ask you one more question. I have an 1000 X10000 matrix . Each iteration in the for loop should select all the [,I] which are all columns how do I do that?

Comment: Do you mean you want to select all the columns given the rows 50 / 100  / 150 etc.? It looks like it since you want `for (1...1000)`, possibly then [i, ]

Comment: yes all the columns at intervals of 50 for which I am using the for loop as you hinted

Comment: if you just want it like that, you can also do it like this: `sapply(seq(1,1000,50), function(x) mean(stored[x,]))`, for taking the mean for example.

Comment: interesting , let me try this. What is stored though ? object 'stored' not found. Seeing this error

Comment: If you want to select every 50th row of a data frame `df`, you can do : `df[seq(1,nrow(df),by=50),]`.